# Difference between "will not do it anymore" and "will not do it again"

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

Does these sentences make sense? What's the difference between these sentences?

> I will not pray to Sananda again.
>   I will not pray to Sananda anymore.
>
> I will not eat too much ice cream anymore.
>   I will not eat too much ice cream again.
>
> I will not watch scary movies anymore.
>   I will not watch scary movies again.
>
> I will not use hypnosis again.
>   I will not use hypnosis anymore.

Answer (score 1):

*Again* means "one more time", while *anymore* means "from now on". That's the main difference.

> I won't do it anymore

to me implies that you'd been doing it a lot when you promised you wouldn't do it anymore, while

> I won't do it again

implies you'd done it once before.

However, the difference can be blurred, and people don't firmly adhere to the descriptions above when using the words *anymore* and *again*.

Comment: Anymore (one word) may be seen as an error in British English, where "any more" is preferred.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't believe that to be the case any longer. *Any more* is definitely the version restricted to British English, while *anymore* isn't quite as restricted. Take a look at the following results in GloWbE: [`anymore`](https://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=68901400), [`any more`](https://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=68901387). Note that *any more* is also used in AmE (as well as BrE) with a separate meaning from *anymore* (I can't account for errors, though, which I would assume are common as they happen to be when such negligible differences are in question).

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/any-more#any-more__14 labels *any more* as BrE, with the alternative spelling of *anymore* occurring in both BrE and AmE.

Comment: Well, I'd mark it as an error.